# XNA Movement Physics and Tracking

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, physics, game-physics

So, I've got a game I'm making and I've run into a snag. I have two sprite, call them A and B. So far, I've been getting A to track B quite simply: get B's position, and if it's X coordinate is greater than A's X coordinate, add A's speed to it's X position. Repeat for and X position less than A's, and Y positions. I also have A pointing where it's going by storing it's old one and setting the rotation using some simple trigonometry. However, now that I've got everything else working, I want to make this a bit more realistic. When B moves quickly from a point left of A to a point right of A, A's angle and movement rapidly jump from pointing and moving bottom-left to bottom-right. I need it to move smoothly. I was thinking of retarding the speed at which A could change it's angle (say, maybe 5 degrees per Update() call), but that wouldn't solve the problem and I'd just end up having A move sideways for a bit. I realize this is a lengthy question and I may not get many answers, but anything you guys could say would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to build a [predator-prey system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation). These are usually modeled with differential equations, but a simple simulation algorithm is [here](http://herselfsai.com/2007/07/simple-predator-prey-chase-algorithms.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend lerping (linearly interpolating) A's tracking of B over time, rather than instantly. Store a Vector2 on `A` that is the position it is actually facing, and lerp that position towards `B` a certain amount each frame, either a hard-coded angle or a certain percentage.

Here's some sample code of lerping a current position toward a desired position.

```
Vector3 current = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 desired = new Vector3(10, 0, -5);

// For this example we will lerp 75% of the way from 'current' to 'desired' per second
Vector3 LerpTowardDesired( Vector3 current, Vector3 desired, float timeDelta )
{
    float lerpPercentage = timeDelta * 0.75f;
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Zero;
    newPos.x = MathHelper.Lerp(current.x, desired.x, lerpPercentage);
    newPos.y = MathHelper.Lerp(current.y, desired.y, lerpPercentage);
    newPos.z = MathHelper.Lerp(current.z, desired.z, lerpPercentage);
}
```

In the above example you would simply call `LerpTowardDesired` once per frame, passing in the elapsed time in seconds as `timeDelta`. Notice `timeDelta` is a float, so the seconds that are passed in include partial seconds (e.g. 0.016 would represent 1/60th of a second, so you wouldn't round to the nearest second and pass 0).

Using the `current` and `desired` vectors we defined above, this is what the results would be over the course of a few frames, assuming a perfect 60fps (frames per second).

```
// After frame 1
current = LerpTowardDesired(current, desired, 0.016f);
// current is now (0.12f, 0.0f, -0.06f)

// After frame 2
current = LerpTowardDesired(current, desired, 0.016f);
// current is now (0.239f, 0.0f, -0.119f)

// After frame 3
current = LerpTowardDesired(current, desired, 0.016f);
// current is now (0.356f, 0.0f, -0.178f)
```

As you can see over 3 frames the `current` position has started moving towards the `desired` position. If you make your sprite always face the `current` position he should track the target sprite over time instead of instantly.

The best thing about using a percentage to lerp with, rather than a hardcoded amount of degrees per frame, is that the faster the target moves, the faster the lerping will occur, because it will be the same percentage of a larger distance. This means that `A` will always keep up with `B` no matter how fast it goes.